# parallel prefix sum down sweep - input size not in powers of 2

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I am implementing the prefix sum algorithm as discussed in http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf. I am facing the problem for input sizes not in powers of 2. I am using this prefix sum implementation for partition in parallel quick sort. Specifically, I am facing the problem in the following down sweep phase algorithm.

```
 x[n – 1] = 0
 for d = log2(n) – 1 down to 0 do 
       for all k = 0 to n – 1 by 2^(d+1) in parallel do 
            t = x[k +  2^d  – 1]
            x[k +  2^d  – 1] = x[k +  2^(d+1) – 1]
            x[k +  2^(d+1) – 1] = t +  x[k +  2^(d+1) – 1]
```

Problem 1 : In the above algorithm, assume n=10, for d=2 and k=8, the index k+2^d–1>n. It is also the case for k+2^(d+1)–1>n. This is leading to application core dump. How should we handle the case for n not in powers of 2?
Problem 2 : For the input sequence 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 the correct prefix sum is 1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4. Consider I am ignoring the operations where index is greater than n. If I calculate by hand I am getting the following prefix sum based on the above paper, 3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0.

Let me know how to handle these problems.

Comment: For problem one, pad the array to a power of 2, perform the operation, then remove the padding.  For problem 2, read the paper more carefully until you're sure that you are doing the right thing.

Comment: You forgot to specify the language

Answer (score -2):

If you are not restricted to some particular language, consider using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) with [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb) for take advantage of [existing parallel prefix algorithm implementation](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_scan_func.htm). Here is an excerpt from the doc.

## Description

A parallel_scan(range,body) computes a parallel prefix, also known as parallel scan. This computation is an advanced concept in parallel computing that is sometimes useful in scenarios that appear to have inherently serial dependences.

A mathematical definition of the parallel prefix is as follows. Let × be an associative operation with left-identity element id×. The parallel prefix of × over a sequence z0, z1, ...zn-1 is a sequence y0, y1, y2, ...yn-1 where:

```
y0 = id× × z0
yi = yi-1 × zi
```

For example, if × is addition, the parallel prefix corresponds a running sum. A serial implementation of parallel prefix is:

```
T temp = id×;
for( int i=1; i<=n; ++i ) {
    temp = temp × z[i];
    y[i] = temp;
}
```

Parallel prefix performs this in parallel by reassociating the application of × and using two passes. It may invoke × up to twice as many times as the serial prefix algorithm. Given the right grain size and sufficient hardware threads, it can out perform the serial prefix because even though it does more work, it can distribute the work across more than one hardware thread.

Comment: I am using cilk with C.